# Задача на gcd, не понятна логика условия

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, теория-чисел

В начале игры у вас есть массив a длины n. За один ход можно выбрать два соседних элемента и заменить один из них на наибольший общий делитель этих двух чисел. То есть из двух соседних чисел x и y можно получить либо gcd(x,y) и y, либо x и gcd(x,y).
за какое минимальное число ходов можно превратить весь массив в единицы.

Есть примеры:

Элемент списка

- 2 2 3 4 6 (результат работы 5)
- 2 6 9 (результат работы 4)
- 2 4 6 8 (-1, т.е. этого добиться невозможно)

Не понимаю почему такие результаты, ведь есть посмотреть например на 2 пример, то можем получить 1 6 3 или 2 1 3, и далее ничего...

Comment: `1 6 3` нельзя получить из `2 6 9`.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте рассмотрим ваш второй пример

```
      2     6    9
gcd      2     3
      2     2    9
gcd      2     1
      2     2    1
gcd      2     1
      1     2    1
gcd      1     1
      1     1    1
```

Все верно, 4 шага...

Как вы получаете `1 6 3` — непонятно, но и эту тройку легко превратить в `1 1 3`, а затем `1 1 1`...

Вот `2 4 6 8` сведется в лучшем случае к `2 2 2 2`, а дальше — никак..

P.S. Кстати, интересная задачка. Если в списке есть 1 — то количество ходов просто равно количеству неединичных элементов. Если есть пара взаимнопростых чисел, стоящих рядом — то просто равно количеству элементов. Если gcd всех элементов не 1 — то ничего не получится. А вот найти кратчайший способ получить хоть одну 1, если все пары соседних элементов не взаимно просты? Как я понимаю, надо искать минимальный набор элементов, у которых gcd == 1, но как это сделать максимально быстро?